# Python: writing an entire row to a CSV file. Why does it work this way?

Tags: python

I had exported a csv from Nokia Suite.

`"sms","SENT","","+12345678901","","2015.01.07 23:06","","Text"`

Reading from the [PythonDoc](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html), I tried

```
import csv

with open(sourcefile,'r', encoding = 'utf8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')
    for line in reader:
    # write entire csv row
        with open(filename,'a', encoding = 'utf8', newline='') as t:
            a = csv.writer(t, delimiter = ',')
            a.writerows(line)
```

It didn't work, until I put brackets around 'line' as so i.e. [line].

So at the last part I had

```
            a.writerows([line])
```

Why is that so?

Comment: The function is called `writerows`. Let me emphasize "row**s**". So it takes a list of rows, not a single row. Change to `writerow` and it will work as you expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `writerows` method accepts a container object. The `line` object isn't a container. `[line]` turns it into a list with one item in it.

What you probably want to use instead is `writerow`.